# Local datetime parsing

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

I am trying to parse an input string to local date time.

Below is my piece of code

```
 ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-26T19:30:00Z", MY_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
```

where

```
MY_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER= new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendLiteral('Z')
            .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "+0000")
            .toFormatter();
```

I get the following exception

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-11-26T19:30:00Z' could not be parsed at index 19

Can you please advise on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: thanks @Jens unfortunately i am not able to change my input string. I just used the hardcoded string as an example. With the input string as-is, can I still parse it?

Comment: can you tell what is your expected output

Comment: Are you sure? I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-11-26T19:30:00Z' could not be parsed at index 20`, note: 20 instead of 19.

Answer (score 3):

## `Instant.parse`

No formatting pattern needed.

```
Instant.parse( "2019-11-26T19:30:00Z" )
```

Your input format complies with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That particular format has a `Z` on the end. That letter means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds), and is pronounced “Zulu”.

The `Instant` class in *java.time* represents a moment in UTC, always UTC.

Using `ZonedDateTime` class for that input is not the most appropriate. We have:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) for values that are always in UTC.
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for moments where only an offset-from-UTC is known but not a time zone. Use this class for UTC values too when you need more flexibility such as generating strings in various formats. `instant.atOffset(
- [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for values in a time zone. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

To view that same moment adjusted to the offset used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-11-26T19:30:00Z" ) ;     // Default format for parsing a moment in UTC.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;                    // A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;                       // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6A21EN).

> instant.toString(): 2019-11-26T19:30:00Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2019-11-26T12:30-07:00[America/Edmonton]

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
.appendZoneOrOffsetId()
```

instead of these two lines:

```
.appendLiteral('Z')
.appendOffset("+HH:mm", "+0000")
```

The whole builder example:

```
MY_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER= new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .appendZoneOrOffsetId()
        .toFormatter();
```

---

P.S. In your specific case I'd rather use the standard ISO formatter (as Hristo mentioned):

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-26T19:30:00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Moreover, the `ZonedDateTime::parse` method will work even without the explicit formatter. Since it's used by default:

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-26T19:30:00Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in ISO zoned time formatter

```
    ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-26T19:30:00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```